# How can I get the camera to keep an entire object in view during an animation?

Tags: animation, camera

I have an animated FBX of a robot that splits into multiple parts during an animation, and then re-forms to make a looping animation.  I have a default camera angle that I normally use, but in this case, several of the robot's parts end up outside the borders of what the camera is focusing on, and therefore not visible when rendering the animation.  Is there a way to make the camera move with the animation to keep 100% of the mesh in the viewport, and then return to its starting position as the animation ends?

Comment: Hello, I don't think that such a fonctionality exists, you can make sure that the camera points towards the object though (with the Damped Track constrraint)

Comment: It was worth a shot.